# MeanJS stack, debugging Angular error: fnPtr is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meanjs

I'm learning the MeanJS stack (Mongo, Express, Angular, Node) and writing a simple todo webapp. I can list all todos and create a new one. When I 'edit' a todo, I'm encountering this error:

```
TypeError: fnPtr is not a function
```

I'm assuming I have some naming or syntax wrong (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208518/angularjs-error-fnptr-is-not-a-function) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870395/angularjs-repeat-and-click) SO question)
The problem is I don't know where to look for wrong naming or bad syntax since the file structure is pretty large ('app' and 'public' maps are 484 files). I don't get into the `todo.client.controller` nor 'todo.server.controller' update function,  as there is a console log there that doesn't get printed. The edit button is a submit input, but I don't know where it goes next.

Code:

Piece form 'edit' page

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-default">
</div>
```

Client controller:

```
    // Update existing Todo
    $scope.update = function() {
        console.log('update');
        var todo = $scope.todo;
        todo.$update(function() {
            $location.path('todos/' + todo._id);
        }, function(errorResponse) {
            $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
        });
    };
```

Server controller:

```
/**Update a Todo*/
exports.update = function(req, res) {
console.log('todo controller');
var todo = req.todo;
todo = _.extend(todo, req.body);
Todo.update({_id: req.body._id}, req.body, function(err, update) {
//todo.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        });
    } else {
        res.json(todo);
    }
});
};
```

Anyone experienced with the MeanJS stack or Angular that could point me in a direction to start debugging?

Comment: your update button does not call the update method in your controller. add this to your <input> tag - `ng-click="update()"`

Comment: It was as simple as that, thank you! If you make an answer, i'll accept

Comment: Although the update functionality is working again, the fnPtr error is still present

Comment: can u show the stack trace ?

Comment: This error mostly occurs when there is a typo in the code. Please check if you have all the brackets right .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not added ng-click to the "Update" submit button.

Change your code to this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="submit" value="Update"  ng-click="update()" class="btn btn-default">
</div>
```

As for the fnPtr error, add your full stack trace so that it can be analyzed.

Also check if your code has closed all the brackets, you are not using same name for 2 variables and typos.